# Python Script on tuning tree in orange datamining

Tags: python, hyperparameter-tuning

Is there any python script that can be used to check the best tuning in tree model on orange python datamining? Since theres an error when I applied the script from

http://docs.biolab.si/orange/2/reference/rst/Orange.tuning.html

Answer (score -1):

The Orange library seems to be a set of data gathering elements that can be used together. Higher-level methods, including classification tree learning, are built from low-level operations, so they are at the bottom of the scale. This makes it simple for developers to add additional functions at whatever level and seamlessly integrate them with the existing version.

The heart of Orange is a set of roughly 200 C++ classes that covers the most basic information formats as well as the bulk of processing and modelling techniques. The Python level also includes popular modules such as num py for linear algebra, network x for working with networks, and matplotlib lib for simple visualization.

Excel, comma, and tab delimited files are all supported by Core Orange (.xlsx, .csv, .tab). It can also read data from the internet, including such spreadsheets created by Google. The PostgreSQL and MSSQL datasets are supported by the SQL widget.

Additional media are loaded via add-ons. For example, the Orange3-ImageAnalytics add-on can import pictures (.jpg,.tiff,.png) and Orange3-Text can import text files (.txt,.docx,.pdf).

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer, so how can we know the best fit tuning for tree widget?